# run phonegap android application on mac

Tags: cordova

I am new to phone gap and finding it difficult to search proper tutorials.
I have the HelloWorld application and want to run it in android.
Installed android platform by using
`cordova platform add android`,
but got the error

```
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/bunty/my-app/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /Users/bunty/my-app/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:700:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:767:5)`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `ANDROID_HOME` path inside your `.bash_profile`.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/your-android-sdk-path/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/your-android-sdk-path/tools
```

Restart your terminal.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't set ANDROID_HOME environmental variable on your Mac.

Open Terminal and configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable based on the location of the Android SDK. Additionally, consider adding ANDROID_HOME/tools, and ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools to your PATH.

> export
>   ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Neel/Documents/Softwares/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk
>
> export
>   PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

then run cordova command to add android platform. It will work.

Comment: you didn't mentioned ANDROID_HOME path.